# Webdriver related I make a python script but and convert in app but webdriver not working

Tags: python, windows, exe

I make a python script and convert into exe file for pc but when i open app its show webdriver have no path

I want how to solve this problem and what is isue
Is this webdriver not install in my app
Or any other method for converting app
I think this is version problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.